# Rails Integration tests don't start fresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, integration-testing, puma

I'm having difficulty running multiple integration tests on Rails 4 (now called system tests in Rails 5).

**Environment**: Rails 4 / Minitest / Capybara / Poltergeist running on the Puma server.

1. When I run a single test that creates a new record, **it works every time**.

   ```
   RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/requests_test.rb -n /create_new/
   ```
2. When I run the entire set of tests, the above test **fails to create every time** because the record already exists.

   ```
   RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/requests_test.rb
   ```

I confirmed this by adding `puts Request.all.collect(&:name)` at the start - when running the group, the record being created already in the DB.

Here's the core issue - **the DB is not reliably fresh for every test**. (It is fresh for my unit tests and my functional tests, in groups and as individuals.) How can I make sure that my integration tests also start fresh each time?

In case it's helpful, the command above seems to be running Puma in development mode, even though I've specified `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` in `test_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the database_cleaner gem (https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)? You can use it to clear the database every time you run a new integration test in your RailsHelper config. I'd check out their documentation but mine looks like:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end

 config.after(:each) do
  FactoryGirl.reload #if you're using FactoryGirl
 end
end
```

Comment: Please provide more context for this answer. Why does it work? Perhaps provide a code sample. See [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for creating a good answer.